# Submenu not showing wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My submenu is not displaying. I've tried all the possible `wp_nav_menu` php, but I just can't get my submenu to show up.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'navigation' )); ?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for this? [Show subnav only][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/display-a-portion-branch-of-the-menu-tree-using-wp-nav-menu/2809#2809

Comment: Hi @StephanWeinhold, not subnav only, but the entire thing. My subnav just does not show up at all.

Comment: What HTML is being output to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you have checked your CSS? Most of the time it's just a display:none-problem.